# Alternative for ReAllocMem that zeros the new allocation

Tags: delphi, memory-management

I need to ReAllocMem a block, but the extension should be zero'ed.

For this reason `ReAllocMem` is no good:

**From the helpfile:**

> ReallocMem reallocates a memory block.
>   [...]
>   **The content of the newly allocated memory is not set to zero.**

I've looked at `ReAllocMemory`, but the help does not state anything about zeroing the new allocation, it only states:

> Note: ReallocMemory is the version of ReallocMem compatible with C++.

Is there an alternative that **does** zero the newly allocated memory?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no. The only raw memory reallocator is ReallocMem. There is nothing else. The design of a re-allocator is always to preserve the contents that were there before. You will have to write your own routine.

Comment: I think Johan only wants to zero the newly allocated stuff, not the stuff that was there before — like SetLength does when lengthening a dynamic array.

Comment: He could simply call `FillChar()` or `ZeroMemory()` after expanding his memory block.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, either of those can set memory to zero

Comment: But having to zero the extension by oneself implies keeping track of the old block size, does it not?

Comment: @Pascal yes, that is so. Of course, what can you do with a pointer to memory of unknown length?

Answer (score 3):

David is right but using WinAp it's possible: you can use Global Alloc and [GlobalReAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the GMEM_ZEROINIT flag.

Comment: Cost of resorting to the global heap is quite high.

Comment: Could be an option for really large blocks of memory.

Comment: @Free - There's no global heap, those functions are wrappers around `HeapAlloc`, `HeapReAlloc`, which are the suggested functions to call to avoid unnecessary overhead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: HeapAlloc performs reasonably well IIRC. Not as well as typical language runtime allocators, but not that much slower. So this is a plausible approach. You'd need to keep your wits about you and make sure everything was done with the right heap!